# Paragraph indent when generating epub from txt in Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, epub

I generate an epub file from a simple txt file using pandoc. The text file text.txt is

> ## Chapter 1
>
> This is the text of paragraph 1.
>
> This is the text of paragraph 2.

I generate an epub using `pandoc -o file.epub text.txt`. However, the paragraphs are not indented. Is there a way to tell pandoc to indent all the paragraphs without having to change the txt file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject some CSS, either from a file with the [`--css` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--css) or by setting the `header-includes` variable, for example:

```
pandoc -V header-includes='<style>p{ margin-left: 1em }</style>' text.txt -o file.epub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, css styling for epubs is a very handy tool. On a side note, margin-left simply enlarges the left margin, for all lines of the paragraph. For indenting only the first line, the correct css is `p { text-indent: 1em }`.